# how can boolean type is returned in this code?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {//   <----- here!
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
<p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will continue to count (is not reset).</p>
</body>
</html>
```

`localStorage.clickcount`  <-- it returns boolean ???

I can't understand it.
because there is no expression like `==` at all.

Answer (score 4):

ECMASCript defines rules to convert expressions to boolean values:

> **9.2 ToBoolean**
>
> - Number : 
>     The result is **false** if the argument is **+0**, **-0**, or **NaN**; otherwise the result is **true**.

Then the statement is equivalent to:

```
if (localStorage.clickcount != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

A term that you may see often in this context is **truthy**. MDN describes it as follows:

> In JavaScript, a **truthy** value is a value that is considered **true** when evaluated in a Boolean context.

Source: **[Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)**

The *if*-statement wants/needs a boolean value. It checks what it got actually fed, and interprets that as either true (truthy) or false (falsy).

Answer (score 0):

These cases return false:

boolean is false
number is 0\NaN
string is ''
var is undefined
var is null

otherwise -> return true